# Como alterar título da página em link externo

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Na minha aplicação tenho um link externo para um pdf, é possivel forçar a alteração do título da página? pois está vindo um MD5 como nome do pdf e fica horrível no titulo do navegador, é possivel forçar a alteração do titulo depois de carregado?

Comment: `document.title = "titulo"` ?

Comment: Mas queria alterar de um link externo, queria uma solução pra isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode usar um iframe?

Dê uma olhada aqui:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp